Create a command with pgf options to import a symbol from a different font
Writing a mathematical document it sometimes happens you need to use some symbols not available in amssymb: to expand this library then I thought to "automate" a standard procedure for importing symbols from some library using pgf but without great success. Below the code I attempted to build.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{amssymbplus}

\RequirePackage{amssymb} 
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs} 
\RequirePackage{yfonts} 
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys} 

\pgfkeys{%
    /symboloptions/.cd,
    name/.store in=\symbol@name,
    name=,
    %
    code/.store in=\symbol@code,
    code=,
    %
    package/.store in=\symbol@package,
    package=,
    %
    style/.store in=\symbol@style,
    style=,
    %
    category/.store in=\symbol@category,
    category=,
}

\newcommand{\newmathsymbol}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/symboloptions/.cd, #1}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{\symbol@package}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{\symbol@package}{m}{n}{<-> s * [1] \symbol@package}{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{\symbol@category}{U}{\symbol@package}{m}{n}
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathord}=0
        \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathord}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
    \else
        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathbin}=0
            \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathbin}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
        \else
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathrel}=0
                \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathrel}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
            \else
                \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathop}=0
                    \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathop}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
                \else
                    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathopen}=0
                        \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathopen}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
                    \else
                        \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathclose}=0
                            \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathclose}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}
                        \else
                            %
                        \fi
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}

\newmathsymbol{name=bbslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='015}

\newmathsymbol{name=boxast,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathbin,category=stxbin,code='265}

\newmathsymbol{name=capdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='075}

\newmathsymbol{name=capplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='077}

\newmathsymbol{name=cupdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='074}

\newmathsymbol{name=cupplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='076}

\newmathsymbol{name=lcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathopen,category=stop,code='351}

\newmathsymbol{name=leftrightharpoon,package=mathb10,style=mathbin,category=matharrows,code='340}

\newmathsymbol{name=longleftwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='305}

\newmathsymbol{name=longrightwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='304}

\newmathsymbol{name=ostar,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='146}

\newmathsymbol{name=ovee,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='066}

\newmathsymbol{name=owedge,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code

='077}
    
    \newmathsymbol{name=rcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathclose,category=stcl,code='352}
    
    \newmathsymbol{name=sslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='014}

So unfortunately the above code does not work: the symbols do not appear as you can verify compiling the following test-code.

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymbplus}

\begin{document}
    $a\bbslash b$
    $a\boxast b$
    $a\capdot b$
    $a\capplus b$
    $a\cupdot b$
    $a\cupplus b$
    $\lcurvyangle a\rcurvyangle$
    $a\leftrightharpoon b$
    $a\longleftwavearrow b$
    $a\longrightwavearrow b$
    $a\ostar b$
    $a\ovee b$
    $a\owedge b$
    $a\sslash b$
\end{document}

So I thought to put here a specific question where I ask how create a command which works as newmathsymbol. Could someone help me, please?

"does not work" is not a sensible problem description. And your code is not complete and so can't be tested.

@UlrikeFischer I updated the question adding a test code and explaining the problem.

What does 'does not work' mean? Do you get an error? Is the output not what you want?

I don't recommend this approach, but it will work if you remove * [1] from the font family declaration and use FdSymbolC-Regular. I also commented a bunch of line endings which would otherwise introduce spurious spaces, but you should check in case I missed some.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{amssymbplus}

\RequirePackage{amssymb} 
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs} 
\RequirePackage{yfonts} 
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys} 

\pgfkeys{%
  /symboloptions/.cd,
  name/.store in=\symbol@name,
  name=,
  code/.store in=\symbol@code,
  code=,
  package/.store in=\symbol@package,
  package=,
  style/.store in=\symbol@style,
  style=,
  category/.store in=\symbol@category,
  category=,
}

\newcommand{\newmathsymbol}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/symboloptions/.cd, #1}%
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{\symbol@package}{}%
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{\symbol@package}{m}{n}{<-> \symbol@package}{}%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{\symbol@category}{U}{\symbol@package}{m}{n}%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathord}=0
      \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathord}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
  \else
      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathbin}=0
          \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathbin}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
      \else
          \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathrel}=0
              \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathrel}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
          \else
              \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathop}=0
                  \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathop}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
              \else
                  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathopen}=0
                      \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathopen}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
                  \else
                      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\symbol@style}{mathclose}=0
                          \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname \symbol@name\endcsname{\mathclose}{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}%
                      \fi
                  \fi
              \fi
          \fi
      \fi
  \fi
}%

\newmathsymbol{name=bbslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='015}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbslash}{\mathbin}{stbin}{'015}

\newmathsymbol{name=boxast,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathbin,category=stxbin,code='265}
% 
\newmathsymbol{name=capdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='075}
% 
\newmathsymbol{name=capplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='077}

\newmathsymbol{name=cupdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='074}

\newmathsymbol{name=cupplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='076}

\newmathsymbol{name=lcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathopen,category=stop,code='351}

\newmathsymbol{name=leftrightharpoon,package=mathb10,style=mathbin,category=matharrows,code='340}

\newmathsymbol{name=longleftwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC-Regular,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='305}

\newmathsymbol{name=longrightwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC-Regular,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='304}

\newmathsymbol{name=ostar,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='146}

\newmathsymbol{name=ovee,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='066}

\newmathsymbol{name=owedge,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='077}
    
\newmathsymbol{name=rcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathclose,category=stcl,code='352}

\newmathsymbol{name=sslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='014}

Your test document compiles fine with these changes.


First of all, thanks for the answer; it seems to me there is only a bit problem with the leftrightharpoon which is different: look mathb10 table at 152 page of raw font tables document.

@AntonioMariaDiMauro Then it is probably the wrong font declaration. Check which font actually has the character you want. (And also the terminal output or log.) Remember that you're using a raw encoding.

I would like to print the symbol '340 of the mathb10 tab at page 152: it is a double harpoon arrow.

I found the typo: the category of longleftwavearrow and that of longrightwavearrow must be fdarrows and not matharrows. Thanks really for the help: answer upvoted and approved.

@AntonioMariaDiMauro Great. Was going to look at this, but it seems you have it all sorted l). I don't know why I wrote that about the encoding, either, since the tables are listing the same (non-)encoding anyhow.

The following is basically the same answer as @cfr's, but the code turned into L3 code, and instead of using a long chain of strcmp it just turns the style into a macro (so style=mathbin results in \mathbin being used).
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{amssymbplus.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage{amssymbplus} {2024-05-28} {0.0} {an extension to amssymb}

\RequirePackage{amssymb} 
\RequirePackage{mathrsfs} 
\RequirePackage{yfonts} 

\keys_define:nn { amssymbplus }
  {
     name     .str_set:N = \l__amssymbplus_name_str
    ,code     .int_set:N = \l__amssymbplus_code_int
    ,package  .str_set:N = \l__amssymbplus_package_str
    ,style    .str_set:N = \l__amssymbplus_style_str
    ,category .str_set:N = \l__amssymbplus_category_str
  }

\group_begin:
  \keys_precompile:nnN
    { amssymbplus } { name, code=0, package, style, category } \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_new_eq:NN \__amssymbplus_reset_keys: \l_tmpa_tl
\group_end:

\cs_new_protected:Npn \amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n #1
  {
    \__amssymbplus_reset_keys:
    \keys_set:nn { amssymbplus } {#1}
    \DeclareFontFamily
      { U }
      { \l__amssymbplus_package_str }
      {}
    \DeclareFontShape
      { U }
      { \l__amssymbplus_package_str }
      { m }
      { n }
      { <-> \l__amssymbplus_package_str }
      {}
    \DeclareSymbolFont
      { \l__amssymbplus_category_str }
      { U }
      { \l__amssymbplus_package_str }
      { m }
      { n }
    \exp_args:Ncc \DeclareMathSymbol
      { \l__amssymbplus_name_str }
      { \l__amssymbplus_style_str }
      { \l__amssymbplus_category_str }
      { \l__amssymbplus_code_int }
  }

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=bbslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='015}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=boxast,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathbin,category=stxbin,code='265}
% 
\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=capdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='075}
% 
\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=capplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='077}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=cupdot,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='074}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=cupplus,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='076}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=lcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathopen,category=stop,code='351}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=leftrightharpoon,package=mathb10,style=mathbin,category=matharrows,code='340}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=longleftwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC-Regular,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='305}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=longrightwavearrow,package=FdSymbolC-Regular,style=mathrel,category=matharrows,code='304}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=ostar,package=MnSymbolC10,style=mathbin,category=mnbin,code='146}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=ovee,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='066}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=owedge,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='077}
    
\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=rcurvyangle,package=stix-mathfrak,style=mathclose,category=stcl,code='352}

\amssymbplus_new_math_symbol:n {name=sslash,package=stmary10,style=mathbin,category=stbin,code='014}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymbplus}

\begin{document}
    $a\bbslash b$
    $a\boxast b$
    $a\capdot b$
    $a\capplus b$
    $a\cupdot b$
    $a\cupplus b$
    $\lcurvyangle a\rcurvyangle$
    $a\leftrightharpoon b$
    $a\longleftwavearrow b$
    $a\longrightwavearrow b$
    $a\ostar b$
    $a\ovee b$
    $a\owedge b$
    $a\sslash b$
\end{document}


Thanks for the answer. :-)

@AntonioMariaDiMauro you're welcome. Of course you could also apply the change of turning the style into a macro to cfr's answer: \expandafter\DeclareMathSymbol\csname\symbol@name\expandafter\endcsname\csname\symbol@style\endcsname{\symbol@category}{\symbol@code}% instead of all the \if...\else...\fi blocks.
